# Understanding Linux routes in Proxmox

Tags: linux, networking, routing, static-routes

I have a server and decided to go ahead and practise with Proxmox. This is the network setup I have right now:

- Two interfaces: eth0 & eth1 (different NICs, both connected to internet)
- Two bridges: vmbr0 (private IP: 192.168.1.200) & vmbr1 (used by the VMs as exit to Internet, so no IP set, VMs are setting it - I have several public IP addresses available for this matter)
- Gateway is 192.168.1.1

The current routes in the server:

> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>
> 192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr0
>
> default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0

Server connection is OK (just going through the gateway). However, I am unable to get connectivity from the VMs. VMs are using vmbr1, which has no route at this moment. I tried to add a default gw route for vmbr1 but did not succeed (*SIOCADDRT: No such process*). What could I be missing?